# Which PHP code is used to maintain the user browser or machine identification

Tags: php, smarty, xajax

Which technology is used to maintain the user browser or machine identification ? After removing all the browser history and cookies ?

Real Time Scenerio:

```
         I am login to axis internet login through my machine with firefox browser,during the first login it will ask the security question.,after that I removed all my history and cookies of my firefox browser.But again login to my axis internet banking from the same machine,It couldn't ask any security question.
         While accessing from different machine at the first time,it will ask the security question and all.,but two different systems are being accessing same internet.
          Which technology is available to maintain the user credentials after removing all the client browser histroy and cookies.,
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I know some websites use 2 ways to check if the user already visited the website and if so perform the desidered actions.

They use:

**Cookies**

They store cookies in your browser and then retrive them when needed

**IP recognition**

They store your IP so even if you delete your cookies they have in their database the information they've stored as cookies and then they can re-add these cookies.

**How to avoid this?**

You can avoid to be recognized by the website turning off your modem for 10/15 minutes if you have a *dynamic* IP address. If you have a static one or your dynamic address do not change so often (depend on your ISP) you could use a proxy.

Comment: Tracking users using IP only is nonse, as most users are behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) connection so one IP may correspond to many users

Comment: Usually if there are more machines on the same IP they detect it and disable the cookies retriving from the db

Answer (score 0):

you can use a local storage for this purpose try with this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)